# Múltiplas conexões com dispositivos usando Sockets

Tags: c#, socket

Tenho um método que se conecta a um leitor de cartão via TCP/Ip (ip, porta) usando Sockets. Para a conexão 1:1 está funcionando, mas agora preciso me conectar a mais de um equipamento simultaneamente. Eu teria que criar uma Thread para cada conexão, ou teria outra maneira de fazer isso? Lembrando que meu sistema é um "client" dos leitores.

Comment: E qual é a dúvida/problema?

Comment: "Eu teria que criar uma Thread para cada conexão, ou teria outra maneira de fazer isso?"

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende dos métodos que está usando para se conectar, enviar e receber dados.

Se estiver usando por exemplo os métodos `Connect`, `Send` e `Receive` eles bloqueiam a execução então seria necessário o uso de Threads, porém isso não é o mais recomendado, o mais recomendado é usar os métodos assíncronos.

Usando os métodos `BeginConnect`, `BeginSend` e `BeginReceive` você não deve ter problemas já que eles não bloqueiam o thread e usam um sistema de Callback para notificar quando terminaram de executar ou receberam dados.

Answer (score 0):

Prezado JcSaint,

Uma implementação de socket não é uma tarefa tão simples, mesmo com as várias abstrações que o .NET oferece.

É possível sim iniciar uma nova thread por conexão mas este não é o método recomendado pois se houver sobrecarga o sistema operacional provavelmente vai matar seu processo.

Em um servidor web que desenvolvi utilizando C++ utilizei a abordagem assíncrona, utilizando 1 thread para recebimento de novas conexões e uma fila (pool) de conexões a qual é processada pelas demais threads físicas disponíveis no hardware (assim obtive melhor desempenho para meu caso), sendo estas devidamente sincronizadas quando necessário.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Neste caso eu teria que implementar algo em c++, gerar uma dll e consumi-la no c# ?

Comment: A mesma implementação pode ser feita em C#, utilizando as sockets prontas do .NET Framework ou outra tecnologia. Coloquei como um exemplo da implementação que fiz em C++ pois não desenvolvi código equivalente em C#, mas é plenamente possível.